# How do I cause an excel cell to update from within a vba module?

Tags: excel, vba

I am still fairly new to VBA coding and for a while I have been having the same issue. In my code I am constantly jumping around an issue where I have a function or sub that performs a task or series of tasks which change any number of variables/values. I also have a number of excel cells that contain functions which retrieve single values - like "`=Get_Density(B1,B2)`" - where B1 and B2 might be mass and volume.

Most of my cells update whenever I change a value on my sheet that pertains to one of the variables within a function. For example if I change cell B1 this will automatically call the `Get_Density()` function to run, which automatically updates the cell.

What I want is when I have a function that has no input parameters or 'if statements' to control when a cell updates - like "`Get_Density()`" - with no parameters... How can I initiate my function externally.

This is just an example, but it is similar to what I am trying to achieve - lets say my values were to come from a userform that's opened from a button on an excel sheet. Lets also say I can input two values - mass and volume. Once I enter two values I click a button which says "Done" and then the program calculates the value for density and sets it equal to a variable in a separate module. Now how do I instantiate the cell which retrieves the value either on a button press or when the user form closes?

I have tried directly setting my cells from within VBA to the value that I want. My only problem with this is that if the position of where I want the value changes then I have to change every instance of it on my code. I have also tried checking for conditions within excel, but this only works for specific instances.

I can show code if needed, but I was hoping there was a method or function within VBA and excel that would achieve what I am looking for. I don't really have code that needs fixing.

Comment: If you had code it would be more helpful to understand your goal. So you want to create a button that you click after you input your variables which then calculates the mass of an object in another cell? At face value that just sounds like that cell should have the formula to mass unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 0):

add the following instruction at the begin of all functions that you want to be reevaluated after entering a new value to your worksheet

```
application.volatile
```